# Config Server stopped propagating changes to the micro-service that was upgraded to Spring Boot 2.4.5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-boot-2

We used to run our micro-services on spring boot 2.2, but we decided to upgrade to the latest SB 2.4.5, in one service we enabled the use of new config profiles.

We use this new feature mostly for local development overrides.

When it comes down to our cloud deployment, config is pushed with the use of the config server.
Unfortunately, config server is not setting some of the properties anymore:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
                                                    • Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'vmr' to com.solace.maas.mop.VMRProperties failed:

    Property: vmr.vpnname
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be empty

    Property: vmr.username
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be empty

    Property: vmr.host
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be empty

    Property: vmr.password
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be empty


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

These `vmr` properties were used to be set by the config server.

Is there something obvious I am missing? Any troubleshooting ideas?

Thanks!

=============UPDATE================

```
  <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Cloud -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.3:compile
```

Comment: You have to update spring cloud to 2020.0.2 and there are a number of breaking changes https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes

Comment: I am using  <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version> Please see updated question

Comment: Is there a chance that the new config client isn't compatible with the old server?

Comment: Did you read the link I sent? Starting with spring cloud 2020.0 you must use spring.config.import=configserver: or add spring cloud starter bootstrap